# Compute $\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{d z}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}$ with the residue theorem

Tags: integration

$$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{d z}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}$$
I calculated the above integral several times using the residue theorem.  The answer I get is $\pi / 2$ but this answer is not in the options please help

1. $\frac{\pi i}{2}$
2. $\frac{-\pi i}{2}$
3. $\frac{\pi i}{1}$
4. 0

My answer

$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{d z}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}$
$1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}=0 \rightarrow z=\pm i, z=-1$
$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{d z}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}=2 \pi i\left(\left.\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}\right)\right|_{z=i}\right)$
$+\pi i\left(\left.\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}\right)\right|_{z=-1}\right)$
$=2 \pi i(-0.25-0.25 i)+0.5 \pi i=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: If you don't show what have you done, we can't show where you made mistakes.

Comment: $\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{d z}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}$
$1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}=0 \rightarrow z=\pm i, z=-1$
$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{d z}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}=2 \pi i\left(\left.\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}\right)\right|_{z=i}\right)$
$+\pi i\left(\left.\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}\right)\right|_{z=-1}\right)$
$=2 \pi i(-0.25-0.25 i)+0.5 \pi i=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @user942771 include that in the question

Comment: Don't post that in a comment, [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4391074/edit) your question.

Comment: Why did you multiply the residue at $-1$ by $1/2$?

Answer (score 4):

You have:

$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{d z}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}$

$1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}=0 \rightarrow z=\pm i, z=-1$

After this you didn't apply the Residue Theorem correctly. Instead of

$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{d z}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}=2 \pi i\left(\left.\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}\right)\right|_{z=i}\right)+\pi i\left(\left.\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}\right)\right|_{z=-1}\right)$

It should be:

$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{d z}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}=2 \pi i\left(\left.\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}\right)\right|_{z=i}\right)\color{red}{+ 2 \pi i\left(\left.\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}\right)\right|_{z=-i}\right)}+\color{red}{2} \pi i\left(\left.\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}\right)\right|_{z=-1}\right)$

I don't know why you ignored the pole at $-i$, and you missed a $2$ in the term of the pole $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z+z^{2}+z^{3}}=\frac{z-1}{z^{4}-1}$$

Then $-1,i,-i$ are simple poles.

When $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ and $h(z)$ has zero of order 1 at $z_{0}$ and $g(z_{0})\neq 0$. Then the residue is $\frac{g(z_{0})}{h'(z_{0})}$.

The residue is given by $\displaystyle Res_{z=z_{0}}\frac{z_{0}-1}{4z_{0}^{3}}$.

$$Res_{z=-1}f(z)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$Res_{z=-i}f(z)=\frac{-1+i}{4}$$

$$Res_{z=i}f(z)=\frac{-1-i}{4}$$.

Add them to get $0$. And hence the integral is $0$ by Residue Theorem.

Comment: You could also do this with one residue fewer by calculating the residue at infinity and subtracting the residue at $1$. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah of course. I wanted to complete the path the op was taking

Comment: I understand completely. Seems OP did everything correctly but only took a half-residue at $-1$ for some bizarre reason.

Comment: @TedShifrin He also ignored the pole at $-i$, also for some bizarre reason.

Comment: Oh yeah, @jjagmath. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

The function $$\frac{1}{z^3+z^2+z+1}$$ is holomorphic on the region *outside* $|z|=2$ on the Riemann sphere, i.e. $\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus B(0,2)$.

But that region is simply connected.  By Cauchy's theorem, we can contract the contour to a point within that region, and the integral of a point vanishes.

Thus the integral is $0$.